# Facebook Like not Pulling Title

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am having some issues with the new facebook like button. It shows up fine, however for some reason it's not pulling the title of the page.

I have the  and I am using og:title, all are filled in, when I view the source of the iframe created on the load of he button, the  in there is blank. I am also trying to put the tweetmeme and that's seeing that title and not the meta, or the normal page title.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://developers.facebook.com/schema/">

<fb:like href="<?=$url?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="100" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

UPDATE: Complete Head

```
<head>


<title>Ladder 15 Gets A New Menu!</title>
<meta content="Growing up can be hard to do, especially in the Mad River family. But Ladder 15 has come into its own over the winter.&nbsp; With some new cocktails, wine selection, a hefty new beer list and veteran Chef David Ansill in the kitchen, you can check your fist pump at" name="Description">
<meta content="" name="Keywords">
<meta content="cities2night inc." name="author">
<meta content="Cities2Night 2010" name="copyright">
<meta content="en-us" name="language">
<meta content="General" name="rating">
<meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="Ladder 15 gets a new menu!" name="tweetmeme-title">
<meta content="Ladder 15 gets a new menu!" property="og:title">
<meta content="article" property="og:type">
<meta content="http://philly.cities2night.com/articles/show/listing/11/ladder-15-gets-a-new-menu" property="og:url">
<meta content="http://philly.cities2night.com/public/article_images/11.jpg" property="og:image">
<meta content="c0176da0ec38aaf107c0ef6c8cdeee38" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="Philly2night.com" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="Growing up can be hard to do, especially in the Mad River family. But Ladder" property="og:description"></head>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where the title is supposed to be ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a development URL?  [This](http://philly.cities2night.com/articles/show/listing/11/ladder-15-gets-a-new-menu) is the page that I see when I visit the link specified by your "og:url", which has the title "Philly2night.com's Articles" and no open graph meta data specified.  I imagine this is probably an issue, as Facebook will likely try to pull info from the available URL.

Also, for the pages you listed that have a good number of "likes" already, you may run into this issue:

> You can update the attributes of your
>   page by updating your page's 
>   tags.  Note that og:title and og:type
>   are only editable initially - after
>   the page receives 10 likes, these
>   properties become fixed to avoid
>   surprising users who have liked the
>   page already, and changing the title
>   or type tags will result in your page
>   losing any existing likes.

From the [FB Open Graph Protocol explanation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph).

Comment: I am using a development site, and I hard coded it now to 1 url, still seems to be pulling the wrong title, It effects the twitter since its the last title tag it sees.

Comment: http://philadelphia.cities2night.com/articles/show/article/11/get-down-and-dirty-with-the-burger-15

This is a example URL, I see all the og data, and the title to be correct, yet if you like it, it still says "Philly2night.com's Articles" This is frustrating.

Comment: Cache might be an issue.  It's correctly sharing the link (with the title) now on FB (and it wasn't earlier), so maybe the "like" functionality will soon follow.

Comment: Here's another http://philadelphia.cities2night.com/articles/show/article/12/city-tap-house-beer-2-0-grand-opening-this-week

Same thing, it's doing I guess a cache, but I haven't changed the code in days on it. So not sure why it's pulling it. If it's our cache browsers, or facebook's, As you can see with the twitter it's pullin the wrong one still.

Comment: See edited answer... might also have something to do with the number of likes you've already attributed to the page.