# Implemented Open Graph Protocol for Facebook Like buttons and works on entire site except for one page, why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have implemented Facebook Open Graph Protocol Full Integration following the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ and http://www.websitedesign411.com/blog/facebook-open-graph-protocol-full-integration-walkthrough.

The Like buttons work and show in the Facebook feeds except for one page www.giantmango.com/contest.  I have tried several alternatives like manually entering the content for the meta tags and an else statement for pages, but I am unable to get Facebook to recognize this page.  Any ideas?

```
<?php } elseif (is_page()) { ?>
        <meta property="og:title" content="「I LIKE CREATORS」 アートチャリティー&コンテストへようこそ！" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="「I LIKE CREATORS」 アートチャリティー&コンテストへようこそ！ 売上の一部は児童養護施設に寄付いたします。2011年2月21日(月)から2月28日(月)好きな作品に投票をして、抽選で10名様にアメリカ生まれのナチュラルケアブランド「バーツビーズ」の福袋またはハンドサルヴが当たります。" />
```

Comment: It's working just fine, check the Facebook [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgiantmango.com%2Fcontest)

Comment: @ifaour:  When I type in the url in a message in Facebook, links usually have a description.  Other links on giantmango.com have descriptions too, but this page giantmango.com/contest does not show one.

Comment: @tokyowp: it's showing the description: http://i53.tinypic.com/2qdo57p.png

Comment: Then it's a caching problem and URL Linter solved it. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with <fb:like> page title, like count, and page url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037400/trouble-with-fblike-page-title-like-count-and-page-url)

Comment: @ifaour:  How to solve "possible duplicate of Trouble with <fb:like> page title, like count, and page url"?  and is the caching problem with my site or Facebook?

Comment: you can't, just up-vote it if you found the answer helpful. and Facebook caches your page data...so it's Facebook related.

Comment: @ifaour:  upvote = "this is a great comment"?  There needs to be a  check button for situations like this so I can close this question.

Comment: I thought you are talking about the other question. Now about this, lets hope other SOers with rep 3000+ vote to close this question.

Comment: @ifaour:  Thank you again for the URL Linter info.  It solved my problem.  If you put an answer to this, I can click the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037400/trouble-with-fblike-page-title-like-count-and-page-url/5039559#5039559), it's a caching problem and quoting from Facebook ([Editing Meta Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)):

> For the changes to be reflected on
>   Facebook, you must force your page to
>   be scraped. The page is scraped when
>   an admin for the page clicks the Like
>   button or when the URL is entered into
>   the Facebook URL Linter.

So basically when I tested your page in the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/), Facebook grabbed (scraped) the *current* data for the open graph meta tags.