# Adding a custom image to facebook like feature

Tags: php, facebook, image, hyperlink, meta-tags

This may seem like a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847210/how-does-facebook-detect-images-when-adding-a-link) or it is easily answered [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/407/) yet I remain utterly befuddled by how easy of a feature this is to implement and how much trouble I am having adding my image and finding a solution that works. I have been scouring to no avail. The two links provided above show the only two options I have found which are:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/styles/images/fb_cl_logo.png"/>
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/Blogs_fb_build.php?id=<?php echo $blog; ?>"/>
```

Needless to say this is not working whatsoever!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i've used facebook's custom image feature, it's taken some time before the facebook feed line item actually fetched the image~ it showed the text of the item first, and then a while later it showed the image~ could it be that you're not giving it a chance~?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implemented Open Graph Protocol for Facebook Like buttons and works on entire site except for one page, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067012/implemented-open-graph-protocol-for-facebook-like-buttons-and-works-on-entire-sit)

Comment: @Shad - That makes sense. Did you use the <meta> or <link>?

Comment: Did you trythe [URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to refetch the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two probable reasons:

1. The url to the image is invalid or the URL is inaccessible by Facebooks crawler.
2. Facebook have cached the thumbnail for your page.

If Facebook have cached the results your page, use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and enter the URL to your page, it will usually break the cache *(can be good to add cache break querystring if it misbehaves)*.

If it isnt a cache problem you will see what information the crawler sees about your page which probably is going to solve your problem.

Another things worth mentioning is that breaking the cache in the debugger doesnt always reflect to the "normal Facebook posting" instantly.

Comment: Adding a query string parameter would make it a different URL …

Comment: Yes, but probably still go to the same page if you add like ?cachebreak=123. Which guarantees it's not in Facebook's cache and you can quickly see if the issue is at your side or an issue caused by FB's cache.

Comment: Ok, for debugging that might help. But i wouldn’t influence any caches FB might have on the original URL, because that’s a different one …

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't link to the image it's hard to be sure, but is your image within the 3:1 aspect ratio which Facebook supports? Many people aren't aware of that restriction. If the image is too wide/tall the [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will still detect it but it won't be rendered in news feed